# How to get set the ringtone in notification

Tags: android

I develop an app that the user can set the ringtone for the specified task

here's the code for appointment.class:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,  
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri)              
    null);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

and the Activity extends to BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    switch (getResultCode()){
        case AppointmentPage.RESULT_OK:
            Log.e("Sample","asdas");
            break;
    }
```

My problem is i dont see Sample in my Logcat. How can i see it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use onActivityResults in your activity for user to save his preference and then retrieve it in your onRecieve to use it

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

switch (requestCode) {
   case 5: {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
          Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if (uri != null) {
           SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("key_for_shared_preference",MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreference.edit();
           editor.putString("selected_ringtone_uri",uri.toString());
           editor.apply();
          }
          break;
      }
   }
 }
}
```

For this to work you need to fire the intent from the same activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,  
RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri)              
null);
startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

and retrieve it in your broadcastReceiver in onReceive every time

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("key_for_shared_preference",MODE_PRIVATE);
   String ringtoneUri = sharedPreference.getString("selected_ringtone_uri","");
   if(!ringtoneUri.contentEquals("")){
       Log.d("ringtone uri",ringtoneUri);
   }
}
```

Comment: It says that cannot resolve method. It is possible to have an onactivityresult in a class that is extended as BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: See the updated answer. You can only receive the results when you call from an activity.